# How to decompress XZ data from a hyper::Response on the fly?

Tags: rust, hyper, xz

I'm downloading an XZ file with [hyper](https://crates.io/crates/hyper), and I would like to save it to disk in decompressed form by extracting as much as possible from each incoming [`Chunk`](https://docs.rs/hyper/0.12.24/hyper/struct.Chunk.html) and writing results to disk immediately, as opposed to first downloading the entire file and then decompressing.

There is the [xz2](https://crates.io/crates/xz2) crate that implements the XZ format. However, its [`XzDecoder`](https://docs.rs/xz2/0.1.6/xz2/read/struct.XzDecoder.html) does not seem to support a [Python-like `decompressobj`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zlib.html#zlib.Decompress.decompress) model, where a caller repeatedly feeds partial input and gets partial output.

Instead, `XzDecoder` receives input bytes via a [`Read`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html) parameter, and I'm not sure how to glue these two things together. Is there a way to feed a [`Response`](https://docs.rs/hyper/0.12.24/hyper/struct.Response.html) to `XzDecoder`?

The only clue I found so far is this [issue](https://github.com/hyperium/hyper/issues/1364), which contains a reference to a private [`ReadableChunks`](https://github.com/seanmonstar/reqwest/blob/5deb5705f5fde6d5efecef9b82af7141d82ac895/src/async_impl/decoder.rs#L364-L403) type, which I could in theory replicate in my code - but maybe there is an easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `XzDecoder` does not seem to support a Python-like decompressobj model, where a caller repeatedly feeds partial input and gets partial output

there's [`xz2::stream::Stream`](https://docs.rs/xz2/0.1.6/xz2/stream/struct.Stream.html) which does exactly what you want. Very rough untested code, needs proper error handling, etc, but I hope you'll get the idea:

```rust
fn process(body: hyper::body::Body) {
    let mut decoder = xz2::stream::Stream::new_stream_decoder(1000, 0).unwrap();
    body.for_each(|chunk| {
        let mut buf: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
        if let Ok(_) = decoder.process_vec(&chunk, &mut buf, Action::Run) {
            // write buf to disk
        }
        Ok(())
    }).wait().unwrap();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked! [Here](https://github.com/mephi42/index-repo/blob/2da8bbf6143c9013b906c059284dd09b83b258d1/src/decoders.rs#L61-L91) is what I ended up with.

Comment: @mephi42 Please post that code as a separate answer. Comments are extremely transient.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [@Laney's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54810306/3832536), I came up with the following working code:

```
extern crate failure;
extern crate hyper;
extern crate tokio;
extern crate xz2;

use std::fs::File;
use std::io::Write;
use std::u64;

use failure::Error;
use futures::future::done;
use futures::stream::Stream;
use hyper::{Body, Chunk, Response};
use hyper::rt::Future;
use hyper_tls::HttpsConnector;
use tokio::runtime::Runtime;

fn decode_chunk(file: &mut File, xz: &mut xz2::stream::Stream, chunk: &Chunk)
                -> Result<(), Error> {
    let end = xz.total_in() as usize + chunk.len();
    let mut buf = Vec::with_capacity(8192);
    while (xz.total_in() as usize) < end {
        buf.clear();
        xz.process_vec(
            &chunk[chunk.len() - (end - xz.total_in() as usize)..],
            &mut buf,
            xz2::stream::Action::Run)?;
        file.write_all(&buf)?;
    }
    Ok(())
}

fn decode_response(mut file: File, response: Response<Body>)
                   -> impl Future<Item=(), Error=Error> {
    done(xz2::stream::Stream::new_stream_decoder(u64::MAX, 0)
        .map_err(Error::from))
        .and_then(|mut xz| response
            .into_body()
            .map_err(Error::from)
            .for_each(move |chunk| done(
                decode_chunk(&mut file, &mut xz, &chunk))))
}

fn main() -> Result<(), Error> {
    let client = hyper::Client::builder().build::<_, hyper::Body>(
        HttpsConnector::new(1)?);
    let file = File::create("hello-2.7.tar")?;
    let mut runtime = Runtime::new()?;
    runtime.block_on(client
        .get("https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/hello/hello-2.7.tar.xz".parse()?)
        .map_err(Error::from)
        .and_then(|response| decode_response(file, response)))?;
    runtime.shutdown_now();
    Ok(())
}
```